# error of creating tables on SQL server 2008 R2 from python3.2 and pyodbc on win7

Tags: python, sql, sql-server-2008, python-3.x, pyodbc

I am trying to access SQL server 2008 R2 from Eclipse pydev   ( python 3.2 ) on win7 .

I need to create a table on database.

The code can be run well. But, I cannot create tables in the database. 
If I print the sql string and run the query from SQL server management studio, no problems.

```
import pyodbc
sql_strc = " IF OBJECT_ID(\'[my_db].[dbo].[my_table]\') IS NOT NULL \n"
sql_strc1 = " DROP TABLE [my_db].[dbo].[my_table] \n"  

sql_stra = " CREATE TABLE [my_db].[dbo].[my_table] \n" 
sql_stra1 = "(\n"
sql_stra1a = " person_id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, \n"
sql_stra1b = " value float NULL, \n"
sql_stra1r = "); \n"

sql_str_create_table = sql_strc + sql_strc1 + sql_stra + sql_stra1 + sql_stra1a + sql_stra1b + sql_stra1r

# create table
sql_str_connect_db  = "DRIVER={SQL server};SERVER={my_db};DATABASE={my_table};UID=my_id; PWD=my_password" 
cnxn = pyodbc.connect(sql_str_connect_db)
cursor = cnxn.cursor()
cursor.execute( sql_str_create_table)
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Are you logging into SSMS with integrated security?  Or with the same Id used in your code?  The Id may not have DDL rights.

Comment: @ocassionalDev, I use the same ID as from SSMS, how to know if the ID has DDL right ?

Comment: OK shouldn't be DDL rights then - is there an error message returned when executing the Python code?

Comment: @ocassionalDev, no error message.

Comment: OK, it may be that SSMS isn't showing the table in the Object Explorer pane straight away - try F5 to refresh the pane or "SELECT * FROM" on the table you've created.

Comment: @ocassionalDev, I have used "refresh" to update tables in SSMS, no useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Autocommit](https://code.google.com/p/pyodbc/wiki/Connection#autocommit) is [off by default](https://code.google.com/p/pyodbc/wiki/Module#connect), add the following to commit your change:

```
cnxn.commit()
```

Some unsolicited advice for making your code more readable:

1. Remove unnecessary escape characters from SQL strings
2. Use triple-quote (`"""`) syntax when defining multiline strings. Newline characters are preserved and don't need to be explicitly added.
3. Use keywords in the [connect](https://code.google.com/p/pyodbc/wiki/Module#connect) function call (this is trivial, but I think it makes formatting easier)

With these changes, your final code looks something like:

```
import pyodbc

sql = """
IF OBJECT_ID('[my_db].[dbo].[my_table]') IS NOT NULL
  DROP TABLE [my_db].[dbo].[my_table]

CREATE TABLE [my_db].[dbo].[my_table]
  (
     person_id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
     value     FLOAT NULL
  )      
      """

cnxn = pyodbc.connect(driver='{SQL Server}', server='server_name',
                      database='database_name', uid='uid', pwd='pwd')
cursor = cnxn.cursor()
# create table
cursor = cursor.execute(sql)
cnxn.commit()
```